# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when find the composition of a product

Tags: python

I read such a problem

> Person A is charged with the task of determining the ages of person B’s three
>   children. B tells A that the product of the children’s ages is 36. After ­considering
>   this clue, A replies that another clue is required, so B tells A the sum of the children’s ages. Again, A replies that another clue is needed, so B tells A that the
>   oldest child plays the piano. After hearing this clue, A tells B the ages of the
>   three children.
>   How old are the three children?

Get a foot in the door to analyze the triples whose product is 36 and tried

```
In [4]: ll = []
   ...: for x in range(1,37):
   ...:     for y in range(1, 37):
   ...:         for z in range(1, 37):
   ...:             if x * y * z == 36:
   ...:                 l = sorted([x, y,z])
   ...:                 ll.append(l)
   ...:                 s = set(ll)
   ...:                 print(s)
   ...:                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-cc3ad95c0d1b> in <module>()
      6                 l = sorted([x, y,z])
      7                 ll.append(l)
----> 8                 s = set(ll)
      9                 print(s)
     10 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I am very confused about the unhashable type list.

Comment: your ll is a list of list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `set` object is implemented with a hash table. That means that all the values you store in it must be hashable (meaning, `hash(value)` must work).

You're trying to build a `set` from a list that contains other lists. Unfortunately lists are not hashable, so you get the error you describe in your title.

There are a few ways to work around this issue. The simplest is to use a `tuple` instead of your inner lists. Tuples are hashable as long as all of their contents are hashable too (and integers are hashable, so they should work for you).

Try changing `ll.append(l)` to `ll.append(tuple(l))` and your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

I am confused why you need a `set()`. Perhaps you could try:

```
ll = []
for x in range(1,37):
    for y in range(1, 37):
        for z in range(1, 37):
            if x * y * z == 36:
                l = sorted([x, y,z])
                ll.append(l)
                #s = set(ll)
                print(l)
```

Which outputs:

> [1, 1, 36]
>   [1, 2, 18]
>   [1, 3, 12]
>   [1, 4, 9]
>   [1, 6, 6]
>   [1, 4, 9]
>   [1, 3, 12]
>   [1, 2, 18]
>   [1, 1, 36]
>   [1, 2, 18]
>   [2, 2, 9]
>   [2, 3, 6]
>   [2, 3, 6]
>   [2, 2, 9]
>   [1, 2, 18]
>   [1, 3, 12]
>   [2, 3, 6]
>   [3, 3, 4]
>   [3, 3, 4]
>   [2, 3, 6]
>   [1, 3, 12]
>   [1, 4, 9]
>   [3, 3, 4]
>   [1, 4, 9]
>   [1, 6, 6]
>   [2, 3, 6]
>   [2, 3, 6]
>   [1, 6, 6]
>   [1, 4, 9]
>   [2, 2, 9]
>   [1, 4, 9]
>   [1, 3, 12]
>   [1, 3, 12]
>   [1, 2, 18]
>   [1, 2, 18]
>   [1, 1, 36]